# AP HTML element isn't removed from the normal flow of HTML in IE6 & IE7

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

I'm using a great jQuery contact form validator from bassistance (http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) is exactly what I'm after and works perfectly in every browser except Internet Explorers 6 and 7.

I've amended the CSS so that instead of presenting an error message when something is input incorrectly or omitted, it changes the textarea/input border from grey to red on http://www.stephblack.co.uk/contact.html

I've used the following CSS: #contact_form label.error {position: absolute; left: -10000px;} which works fine on most browsers. In IE6&7 the error messages aren't displayed, but it's forcing the elements below it down, making the whole thing messy.

I've tried everything! AP with a large left position is the most accessible way to do it, so I'd like to stay with that, but I've tried {display: none;}, {height: 0; width: 0; overflow: hidden;}, installed firebug lite to make sure I'm grabbing a hold of the correct element. Maybe it's the Javascript- I've tried removing the error message in the jquery.validate.js file but the problem still occurs. I'm at a loss and I've spent hours on this : (

Feel free to have a look at the code on the site- HTML, CSS, Javascript etc. and let me know what you would change.

Your help is very much appreciated!

Thanks,

Martin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while I can't reproduce the error, as in it's working fine in IE7 for me with the CSS as it is, you might try this, still accessible and just clips the content of the error message (is that what you want?)

```
#contact_form label.error {
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px); /* IE6 */
  clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
}
```

what I might change is to not have that error message in a `label` - a form element should only have one label, as you're concerned with the best accessible hiding method -  but changing it to a div or span should not affect the CSS (apart from changing e.g. `label.error` to `span.error`)

---

#### Update: per comments

> I took the `jquery.validate.js` and
>   changed the line (207) `errorElement:
>   "span",` from `label` - then the above
>   code - `#contact_form span.error` - and
>   probably your negative left
>   positioning now works, for some reason
>   IE7 is picking up the `span` but not the
>   `label`?

Comment: Thanks clairesuzy, I tried the new CSS and it works fine in all the nice browsers but not in the naughty ones! I've double checked in IE7 and it's definitely not working : (

If you go to the contact page and click the send button big gaps appear after the text inputs and a small gap after the textarea.

Maybe there's something in the javascript file jquery.validate.min that I need to change...

Comment: @Martin - I see it now but only when not in a local environment,  IE7 on VPC.. as far as I can see with the dev toolbar, IE7 is not applying the `label.error` it, the error message, is appearing as a text node will need to look closer at the script, can't figure out why it's working locally though :o

Comment: I changed the position to 'right' instead of 'left' and, in both IE6 and 7 the distance between the error input boxes is the same as before but the error text appears on the right side of the page (10000px over). I don't know whether this is a clue or not... Is it useful if I put Firebug Lite back on the page? I've done so for good measure. Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: @Martin - I took the `jquery.validate.js` and changed the line (207) `errorElement: "span",` from `label` -  then the above code - `#contact_form span.error` and probably your negative left positioning now works, for some reason IE7 is picking up the `span` but not the `label` ?

Comment: You're Welcome, weird one.. I updated the answer with the comment - maybe someone will come along with a definitive reason some day ;)